# Patterns for Multiple Input Single Output

Tags: design-patterns

What type of pattern would you recommend for a "multiple input, single output" situation. In other words, I have many different methods that I would like to call to send messages along a single serial port. What are the various patterns available to me and what are the tradeoffs involved in each. I know this is short on specifics, but I'm sure that you will all educate me and I will be able to add to the discussion as it continues. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to apply a design pattern to everything.  This is just a [producer/consumer scenario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem), with multiple producers and one consumer.  A simple implementation is a synchronous blocking queue, like Java's `BlockingQueue`/[`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html).